# How do I get started using ESAPI WAF?

Tags: appsec, owasp, waf, esapi

I've been to the OWASP Enterprise Security API (Java Edition) Google Groups page and found this information missing.

Comment: Found the author's blog entry about the WAF release at, http://i8jesus.com/?p=96.  It has a link to a detailed pdf that will certainly help.

Answer (score 2):

You might try the [wiki](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Enterprise_Security_API#tab=Java_EE) or [javadocs](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/index.html).

Comment: The OWASP wiki has not been helpful to me.  I never seem to find what I am looking for.  The javadocs is what I would use once I was digging in deep.  Just want to know how to get started with the tool.

Answer (score 1):

Start with `org.owasp.esapi.waf.ESAPIWebApplicationFirewallFilter`.
From the [javadocs](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/waf/ESAPIWebApplicationFirewallFilter.html):

> This is the main class for the ESAPI Web Application Firewall (WAF). It is a standard J2EE servlet filter that, in different methods, invokes the reading of the configuration file and handles the runtime processing and enforcing of the developer-specified rules. Ideally the filter should be configured to catch all requests (/*) in web.xml. If there are URL segments that need to be extremely fast and don't require any protection, the pattern may be modified with extreme caution.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for ESAPI is sparse at best. Here are a few nuggets that might help:

- [Web Application Firewall Policy File Specification](https://pdf.yt/d/GJ5MbJo63rhAhkaf)
- [Configuring ESAPI for Web Applications](http://do-while-true.blogspot.ca/2012/02/esapi-for-java-web-applications.html)
- [OWASP ESAPI Authenticator Tutorial](http://technicalmumbojumbo.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/owasp-esapi-authenticator-tutorial/)
- [WAF Filter Test Harness](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/source/browse/trunk/src/test/java/org/owasp/esapi/waf/WAFFilterTest.java?r=565) (versions after r565 abstract the code)